# How to keep randomizing colors in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I just started learning p5.js myself and I have a question with randomizing colors. Right now I see that the color will be reset randomly only when I restart the code. But is it possible to make it happen whenever mouse is pressed?

Here is my code:

```js
let r, g, b; 

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  r = random(255);
  g = random(255);
  b = random(255);
}

function draw() {
  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    fill(r,g,b);
  } else {
    fill(255);
  }
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 80, 80);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create new `r`, `g` and `b` values when the mouse is pressed:

```js
let r = 255, g = 255, b = 255; 

function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function mousePressed() {
    r = random(255);
    g = random(255);
    b = random(255);
}

function draw() {
    fill(r, g, b);
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 80, 80);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Rabbid76 is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72332172/6243352) that you need to overwrite the `r`, `g`, `b` variables if your goal is to persist those values after the mouse is released, but I'd suggest doing it inside the `mousePressed` global function so that multiple triggers won't occur.

```js
let r;
let g;
let b;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  randomizeColors();
}

function draw() {
  fill(r, g, b);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 80, 80);
}

function mousePressed() {
  randomizeColors();
}

function randomizeColors() {
  r = random(255);
  g = random(255);
  b = random(255);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```